# Debugging cucumber.js test

Tags: debugging, cucumber

I wonder if there are better ways to debug cucumber.js test rather than logging on console.

It seems like [CukeStall](https://github.com/jbpros/cukestall) is related to my requirement, but I can't use it because my application is not node.js app.

Any help or comments are appreciated.

Comment: What kind of app are you testing? And in what context is Cucumber.js being run (browser or console)?

Comment: Sorry for insufficient information on my question. I'm working on a project which is using Liferay + knockout.js + Spring MVC. Since I'm using knockout.js which is MVVM library, I'm testing from ViewModel layer. Cucumber is being run on console. I wonder if I can use [node debugger for eclipse](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Using-Eclipse-as-Node-Applications-Debugger) for this purpose. Possible?

Comment: CukeStall is only an experiment at the moment, unfortunately. Your best option is to use Cucumber.js on the CLI (or through an IDE) and plug in something like Selenium, PhantomJS or anything else that can simulate or automate a web browser.